# Django:python manage.py not woroking but python2.7 manage.py is

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv

I HAVE A Weird Kind of Error.When I run manage.py in virtualenv it shows me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
   from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

But when I run

> python2.7 manage.py

it gives me the correct results.I could not understand what error it is and how to fix it because I do not want every time to type python2.7
Also when I run

> pip freeze > requiremts.txt

it's not showing the complete packages installed but they are installed in the site-packages within the the virtualenv.
Now what error is this, anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

Activate the virtual env:

```
. virtual_env_dir/bin/activate
```

Comment: my virtualenv is working perfectly.All i need is to get clarified about why python manage.py is not working and python2.7 manage.py is   **inside virtualenv** and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the manage.py in your project is not compatible with the django version your system loads.

1. Make sure you are have activated your virtualenv, if you have your prompt should somewhat like that (the fact that pip freeze doesn't show the correct list of package makes me believe this is the case):

> ```
>   (virtualenvname) user@machine pwd $
> ```

1. If your prompt doesn't look like that, your virtualenv is not activated, run

> ```
>   source <path-to-env>/bin/activate
> ```

If your are indeed in a virtualenv activated shell, you should probably re-install the package according to the requriements.txt, the problem is that you just overwrote it by pip freezing to it. So if you have a backup of your requirements.txt, put it back up and run

> pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: my virtualenv is working perfectly.All i need is to get clarified about why python manage.py is not working and python2.7 manage.py is inside virtualenv and how to fix it

Comment: if your virtualenv is actually working perfectly it means that the django version installed inside your virtualenv is not compatible with the django version that was used to create manage.py you are using.

The reason it works with python 2.7 is probably because you have the correct django version (eg the one used to create manage.py) installed in your /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ (or whatever your path your distribution uses)